Open sets on a surface with locally connected boundary
Let $\Sigma$ be a surface and $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\Sigma$. Suppose that $\Omega$ is homeomorphic to the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and is relatively compact in $\Sigma$. I'm interested in the 'boundary behaviour' of maps $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to\Omega$ when $\partial\Omega$ is locally connected.
When $\Sigma$ is the complex plane or the Riemann sphere, then the Caratheodory-Torhorst Theorem can be used to show that there exists a homeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to\Omega$ which can be continuously extended to $\overline{\varphi}:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\to\overline{\Omega}$, where the bar denotes closure in its respective space. (Here, the map $\overline{\varphi}$ need not be a homeomorphism.)
I want to know whether this is true on general surfaces.

If $\partial\Omega$, the boundary of $\Omega$, is locally connected, does there exist a homeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\to\Omega$ which can be continuously extended to $\overline{\varphi}:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\to\overline{\Omega}$?

If this is not true in general, when can we guarantee the existence of such $\varphi$ and $\overline{\varphi}$?

The issue is purely local, hence the standard proof of the CT theorem works for subsets of Riemann surfaces (you have to quote the uniformization theorem, of course, to get a conformal map $\varphi$).

@MoisheKohan Could you please elaborate your argument? The proof of the CT theorem I'm aware of relies on Janiszewski's theorem, which relies on winding numbers...

To expand my comments. The proof of the Caratheodory-Torhorst Theorem that I know is given in sections 15, 16 of Milnor's notes "Dynamics in one complex variable". The proof is quite long and I will not reproduce it here. Milnor proves extenstence of a continuous extension of Riemann mapping $\mathbb D\to \Omega\subset S^2$, where $\Omega$ is a simply-connected open subset with locally connected boundary in $S^2$. But if you look in his proof, it is local with one exception, in the proof of Theorem 15.3. There he uses two facts from classical complex analysis:

(Fatou Theorem): Suppose that $f: \mathbb D\to \mathbb C$ is a bounded holomorphic map. Then the radial limit
$$
f(e^{i\theta}):=\lim_{t\to 1-} f(te^{i\theta})
$$
exists for almost all $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.

(Theorem of F. and M. Riesz) In the setting of (1), for each $w\in \mathbb C$ the set
$$
E=\{\theta\in [0,2\pi]: f(e^{i\theta})=w\}
$$
has measure zero.


Using a trick with a ramified covering, Milnor proves that (1) and (2) still hold for conformal maps $f: \mathbb D\to \Omega$ for arbitrary open subsets $\Omega\subset S^2$.
Let us verify that (1) and (2) still hold for conformal maps $f: \mathbb D\to \Omega\subset \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary Riemann surface and $\Omega$ is a relatively compact open subset of $\Sigma$.   It suffices to consider the case when $S$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$ (since, due to the uniformization theorem) the matter reduces to the case of conformal maps to $S^2$ which is already done by Milnor.
Case 1: $\Sigma$ is noncompact. Then $\Sigma$ is a 1-dimensional complex Stein manifold (as proven by Behnke and Stein). hence, $\Sigma$ holomorphically embeds in ${\mathbb C}^N$ for some $N$. (Actually, $N=3$ suffices but we do not need this fact.)
By composing with this embedding, our map $f$ becomes a bounded (since $\Omega$ is relatively compact) holomorphic map
$$
F=(f_1,...,f_N): \mathbb D\to \mathbb C^N. 
$$
But (1) and (2) hold for each holomorphic function $f_k: \mathbb D\to \mathbb C$ (they are all bounded since $F$ is). Since the finite union of measure zero sets still has measure zero, (1) and (2) hold for the map $F$. Now, the rest of Milnor's proof goes through and we obtain the desired continuous extension of a conformal embedding $f: \mathbb D\to \Sigma$ (whose image is relatively compact and has locally connected boundary).
Case 2: $\Sigma$ is compact. The idea of the proof is similar to Milnor's. Since $\Sigma$ is not simply-connected, there exists a 2-hold holomorphic covering map $p: X\to \Sigma$, where $X$ is another Riemann surface. Since $\mathbb D$ is simply-connected, the map $f: \mathbb D\to \Omega\subset \Sigma$ lifts to a holomorphic embedding $\tilde f: \mathbb D\to X$. But $p^{-1}(\Omega)$ consists of two components, $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$. Assume that $\tilde f(\mathbb D)\subset \Omega_1$. Pick a point $w\in \Omega_2$ and set $Y:= X\setminus \{w\}$. This is a noncompact Riemann surface and $\tilde f: \mathbb D\to Y$ is a holomorphic embedding with relatively compact image (since $w$ does not belong to the closure of $\Omega_1$). Since $p$ is a covering map (of finite degree), the boundary of $\Omega_1$ is still locally connected. hence, by Case 1, $\tilde f$ extends to a continuous map $\tilde g: cl(\mathbb D)\to Y\subset X$. Composing $\tilde g$ with $p$ we obtain the desired continuous extension of the original map $f$. qed

Thank you for your interesting answer! Considering one of your last claim about the local connectedness of $\partial \Omega_1$ (a fact I was struggling with in my original answer), you led me to check Milnor's book, and this allowed me to prove this fact and to edit my answer. Thanks!

A comment/question on a correct interpretation of your argument in Case 1. Let $g:\Sigma \to \mathbb{C}^N$ be the embedding. By Milnor's lemma 16.5, each $U_k := (\mathrm{proj}_k \circ g)(U)$ is relatively compact with locally connected boundary. By the CT theorem, each $f_k = \mathrm{proj}_k \circ g \circ f : \mathbb{D} \to U_k$ extends to a continuous $\bar{f_k}:\bar{ \mathbb{D}} \to \bar{U_k}$. Hence $\bar{F} = (\bar{f_1}, \dots, \bar{f_N}): \bar{\mathbb{D}} \to cl(g(U)) = g(\bar{U})$, and $\bar{f} = g^{-1}\circ \bar{F} : \bar{\mathbb{D}} \to \bar{U}$ is the sought-after extension? Thanks

@JordanPayette: No, you cannot use the CT theorem this way.

Thanks for your reply. I fail to see why we cannot use the CT theorem this way, but again I was also mistaken when I thought I had proved that lifts of $\Omega$ have locally connected boundaries, so it's time for me to get away from the monitor and the keyboard!

@JordanPayette: CT theorem is only valid for injective holomorphic maps and the coordinate maps $f_k$ need not be injective.

Thank you! It confirms I need to take some walk!

Context: Let $\Sigma$ be an orientable surface and $\Omega \subset \Sigma$ a relatively compact open subset that is homeomorphic to the unit open disk $\mathbb{D}$ and whose boundary $\partial \Omega$ is locally connected. (We shall write $\mathbb{D}_r$ to denote the radius $r$ open disk centred at $0$.) We may assume that $\Sigma$ is equipped with a metric (which generates its topology). Let $\pi : \widetilde{\Sigma} \to \Sigma$ be the universal cover of $\Sigma$ and $\widetilde{\Omega}$ be some lift of $\Omega$ to $\widetilde{\Sigma}$.

Here's a characterization of when your question admits a positive answer:
Lemma 1. The following are equivalent:

There exists a homeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ which extends to a continuous map $\bar{\varphi} : \bar{\mathbb{D}} \to \bar{\Omega}$.
$\widetilde{\Omega}$ is relatively compact with locally connected boundary $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$.

Proof. 1 implies 2. By the lifting property of $\pi$, we have $\widetilde{\bar{\varphi}} : \bar{\mathbb{D}} \to \widetilde{\Sigma}$ such that $\bar{\varphi} = \pi \circ \widetilde{\bar{\varphi}}$. It is clear that $Z := \widetilde{\bar{\varphi}}(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$ is compact with connected, locally connected boundary and $\widetilde{\Omega} \subset Z$. We have $\overline{\widetilde{\Omega}} = Z$: indeed, clearly, $\overline{\widetilde{\Omega}} \subseteq Z$ and so $\widetilde{\Omega}$ is relatively compact; for $z \in \partial Z$, $x := \pi(z) \in \bar{\varphi}(\bar{D}) = \bar{\Omega}$, so there exists a sequence $\{x_i\}_i \subset \Omega$ such that $x_i \to x$, each $x_i$ has a unique lift $z_i \in \pi^{-1}(x_i) \cap \widetilde{\Omega}$ and the sequence $\{z_i\}_i$ necessarily converges to $z$, whence $z \in \overline{\widetilde{\Omega}}$.
2 implies 1. Since $\Sigma$ is a surface, $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is homeomorphic to either the sphere $S^2$ or the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$; we can equip $S^2$ with its usual complex structure, and we can equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex structure that gives $\mathbb{C}$. According to the Caratheodory--Torhorst theorem, there exists a conformal homeomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{D} \to \widetilde{\Omega}$ which extends to a (surjective) continuous map $\bar{\psi} : \bar{\mathbb{D}} \to \overline{\widetilde{\Omega}}$. Set $Y := \pi(\overline{\widetilde{\Omega}})$; $Y$ is connected and compact and $\Omega \subset Y$. In fact we have $Y = \bar{\Omega}$: clearly $\bar{\Omega} \subseteq Y$; for $x \in Y$, let $z \in \pi^{-1}(x) \cap \overline{\widetilde{\Omega}}$, consider a sequence $\{z_i\}_i \subset \widetilde{\Omega}$ such that $z_i \to z$ and set $x_i := \pi(z_i) \in \Omega$, thus $x_i \to x$ and thus $x \in \bar{\Omega}$. Finally, we set $\varphi := \pi \circ \psi$ and $\bar{\varphi} := \pi \circ \bar{\psi}$.
(Remark: According to the uniformization theorem, another option would have been to equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a complex structure that turns it into the unit open disk in $\mathbb{C}$. However, the statement of the Caratheodory--Torhorst theorem does not include this case, hence our choice above.) QED

Your question thus becomes: In the context above, is $\widetilde{\Omega}$ relatively compact with $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$ locally connected? I guess the answer is 'yes' (especially in view of Moishe Kohan's answer), but I struggle with proving directly that $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$ is locally connected...
Lemma 2. $\widetilde{\Omega}$ is relatively compact in $\widetilde{\Sigma}$.
Proof. We may assume that $\Sigma$ is not the sphere, hence $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is homeomorphic to the plane. By Heine--Borel, it suffices to show that $\widetilde{\Omega}$ is bounded. We suppose otherwise: let $\{z_i\}_i \subset \widetilde{\Omega}$ be an unbounded sequence such that all $z_i$ belong to different fundamental domains of $\pi$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that the distance between any two $z_i$s is greater than some $\delta > 0$ (with respect to the metric lifted from $\Sigma$).  Set $x_i = \pi(z_i) \subset \Omega$; without loss of generality (passing to a subsequence if necessary), we have $x_i \to x$ for some $x \in \bar{\Omega}$. In fact $x \in \partial \Omega$, since $\pi : \widetilde{\Omega} \to \Omega$ is a homeomorphism and $\{z_i\}_i$ has no convergent subsequence.
Consider a small open ball $x \in B \subset \Sigma$ of radius $\delta/2$; without loss of generality, we may assume $\{x_i\}_i \subset B$, in fact even inside the ball $B'$ of radius $\delta/4$ centred at $x$. All $x_i$ belong to different connected components $B_i$ of $B \cap \Omega$. (If $x_i$ and $x_j$ belonged to the same connected component $B_i$, as $B_i$ is path-connected, there would be a continuous path inside $B_i$ connecting $x_i$ to $x_j$, so by the lifting property of paths for $\pi$, $z_i$ and $z_j$ would belong to the same lift of $B$ to $\widetilde{\Sigma}$, hence $dist(z_i, z_j) < \delta$, a contradiction.) Within each $B_i$, there is a simple continuous path $\gamma_i$ connecting $x_i$ to $\partial B$. (Indeed, all $z_i$s are (simple) path-connected in $\widetilde{\Omega} \cong \mathbb{D}$, and these paths necessarily cross the corresponding lifts of $\partial B$ around the $z_i$s.) Hence setting $A = B \setminus \bar{B'}$, all the intersections $A \cap B_i$ are nonempty; more than that, each $\gamma_i$ (has a portion $\gamma'_i$ which) connects the inner boundary of $A$ to the outer boundary of $A$ within $A \cap B_i$.
Any two $\gamma'_i$ and $\gamma'_j$ ($i \neq j$) are separated by (a connected component $C_k$ of) $\partial \Omega \cap A$ (that also 'connects' the inner boundary of $A$ to its outer boundary). As there are infinitely many $i$s, there are infinitely many disjoint such $C_k$s. For each $C_k$, pick some point $x'_k$ at a distance $3\delta/4$ from $x$; there is a subsequence of those $x'_k$ which therefore converge to $x' \in \partial \Omega$ such that $dist(x, x') = 3\delta/4$.
Since $\partial \Omega$ is locally connected, there exists a small open set $x' \in U \subset A$ such that $U \cap (\partial \Omega)$ is connected. This implies that $U$ can intersect at most one $C_k$, but by construction, it also contains infinitely many $x'_k$s. That's a contradiction. Hence $\widetilde{\Omega}$ is bounded. QED
Next I submit:
Conjecture. $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$ is locally path-connected, hence locally connected.
The following results might be of some use in a proof of this conjecture.
Proposition 1. $\partial \Omega$ and $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$ are connected.
Proof. For $\partial \Omega$, suppose it is not connected: there are two disjoint open subsets $V_1, V_2 \subset \Sigma$ such that $\partial \Omega \subset V_1 \cup V_2$ and $V_1 \cap \partial \Omega, V_2 \cap \partial \Omega \neq \varnothing$. If $h : \mathbb{D} \to \Omega$ is a homeomorphism, then given any outer annulus $A_r = \mathbb{D} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{D}}_r$ ($0<r<1$), we have $V_1 \cap h(A_r), V_2 \cap h(A_r) \neq \varnothing$. Hence $h(A_r) \not \subset V_1 \cup V_2$ by connectedness of $h(A_r)$; pick $x_r \subset h(A_r) \setminus (V_1 \cup V_2)$. Since $\Omega$ is relatively compact in $\Sigma$, the net $\{x_r\}_{0<r<1}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{r_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ (with $r_i \to 1$) converging to $x_{\infty} \in \partial \Omega$. By the absurd assumption, $x_{\infty}$ belongs to either $V_1$ or $V_2$, say $V_1$; by convergence of the subsequence, $x_{r_i} \in V_1$ for all sufficiently large $i$, which is a contradiction.
The case of $\partial \widetilde{\Omega}$ follows from the corresponding argument, except that we use Lemma 2 to get the relatively compactness of $\widetilde{\Omega}$. QED
Proposition 2. $\bar{\Omega} = \pi(\bar{\widetilde{\Omega}})$ and $\partial \Omega = \pi(\partial \widetilde{\Omega})$.
Proof. Using Lemma 2, we deduce $\bar{\Omega} \subseteq \pi(\bar{\widetilde{\Omega}})$. Besides, $\pi(\partial \widetilde{\Omega}) \subseteq \partial \Omega$. QED
The following fact (stated/proved as Lemma 16.3 in Milnor's Dynamics in one complex variable) might also help in a proof of the 'conjecture'.
Fact. If a compact metric space $X$ is locally connected, then it is locally path-connected. Hence every connected component of $X$ is actually path-connected.
